# Splitting a column into two columns with different data types

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to separate the last digits in this column in order to put into another column, since the last digits correspond to the volume of the product. Currently the column looks as follows:

```
             Producto
0      SIR EDWARD'S BLENDED 70
1      SIR EDWARD'S BLENDED 70
2      SIR EDWARD'S BLENDED 70
3            DILLON BLANCO 100
4    SAINT JAMES BLANC 55º 100
Name: Producto, dtype: object
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
           Producto         |   CL
0      SIR EDWARD'S BLENDED |   70
1      SIR EDWARD'S BLENDED |   70
2      SIR EDWARD'S BLENDED |   70
3            DILLON BLANCO  |   100
4    SAINT JAMES BLANC 55º  |   100
Name: Producto, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.str.rsplit()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html), as follows:

```
df[['Producto', 'CL']] = df['Producto'].str.rsplit(' ', n=1, expand=True)
```

If you want to convert column `CL` to integer, you can further use:

```
df['CL'] = df['CL'].astype(int)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

                Producto   CL
0   SIR EDWARD'S BLENDED   70
1   SIR EDWARD'S BLENDED   70
2   SIR EDWARD'S BLENDED   70
3          DILLON BLANCO  100
4  SAINT JAMES BLANC 55º  100
```

Answer (score 0):

use regexp and `str.extact` to extract infomation.

```py
dfn = df['Producto'].str.extract(r'(.*)\s+(\d+)$')
dfn.columns = ['Producto', 'CL']
dfn['CL'] = dfn['CL'].astype(int)
```